# How to get number of Installation (collection) ? To get number of push recipient

Tags: php, push-notification, parse-platform

I need to get number of Push recipient, via PHP. So I tried to 'query' the Installation (collection) without success. Any tips or work around ? I'm new on Parse.com Thanks.

Go this error :

> Parse\ParseException: Clients aren't allowed to perform the find operation on the installation collection.

Here my code

```
// Initialisation
require_once('parse_sdk/autoload.php');
Parse\ParseClient::initialize($ws_push_APPLICATION_ID, $ws_push_REST_API_KEY, $ws_push_MASTER_KEY);
$query = new Parse\ParseQuery("_Installation");
$results = $query->find();
```

Any tips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ParseClient has a _request() method. Pass true as the final argument to use the Parse master key. You need to use the master key in order to query Installations.

```
// Count no. of installations
$queryString = http_build_query( array('limit'=>0, 'count'=>1, 'where'=>'{"appName":"myAppName"}') );
$result = ParseClient::_request('GET',
    '/1/installations'.
    '?' . $queryString, null, null, true);
return $result['count'];
```